# Private keys in Microsoft Management Console (mmc) not deleted correctly

Tags: windows, certificate, mmc

I have stumbled across a very weird behavior of mmc in the context of Windows-My.
Steps to reproduce:

- Import a certificate with its respective private key into mmc. In my case I imported a .p12 file.
- Delete the previously added entry.
- Add the certificate to mmc (without the private key). In my case I imported a .pem file that contains exclusively the public key.
- Execute the following Java code (I have used Java 17):

```
KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("Windows-My", "SunMSCAPI");
keyStore.load(null, null);
```

- Refresh mmc and observe that the private key is again attached to the certificate, although it should have been deleted.

My question: Is this expected behavior? If so, why?
If this is not expected behavior, then I assume it is a bug.

For convenience, here the commands that I have used to create the certificate and the private key:

```
openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem -days 365 -nodes
openssl pkcs12 -export -out keystore.p12 -inkey key.pem -in cert.pem
```